# Transparent white PNG to SVG vector

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, inkscape, svg, png

I'm designing a logo and my customer already had a transparent PNG with some white letters on it.

[image: Here it is]

Now I need it to be a vector, but I can't shape the text like thate, so I thought that it would be easier to select the white letters and convert them to SVG (vector).

I've seen some posts in many forums but none of them seems to have these requirements.

Do you know any way to do this in Inkscape, Illustrator...?

Comment: I can also export the image to black or any color, if it is necessary

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Juan, have you also tried to [trace](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html) your logo directly in Inkscape?

Comment: @PaoloGibellini I didn't know that feature! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Solved, I had to use a tool called "Silhouettes" in Illustrator, export to SVG (vector), open with Inkscape and ungroup the four letters.